# Firebase Firestore for Swift doesn't seem to be reaching Google Cloud

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement Firestore on my Swift app and I have hit a slight bump in the road.

I am using this function to add an `Event` object as a document to an `Events` collection. the function appears to be working as I am getting a Document ID returned to me, However looking through the Firebase console I can only see the document I added from the console.

```
func addEvent(event: Event){
    print("")
    print("Running addEvent()")
    print(event.toArray())
    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
    ref = db.collection("Events").addDocument(data: event.toArray())
        { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
                }
            }
    print(ref?.documentID)
}
```

To be sure it wasn't the Firestore rules, I set it to accept all incoming connections

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

***If you need to know***

I have the following code to call the function (inside a `viewDidLoad()` that get's called right as the app is loading up):

```
let ch = CalendarHandler()
let event = Event("nil", title: "Test", date: "1", month: "4", year: "2021", start: "12:00", end: "13:00", count: "0", creator: "me", privacy: "1", allDay: "1")
ch.addEvent(event: event)
```

and the console outputs this when the function is called:

```
Running addEvent()
["day": "1", "month": "4", "start": "12:00", "year": "2021", "isPrivate": true, "count": "0", "title": "Test", "isAllDay": true, "end": "13:00", "creator": "me"]
Optional("Ig8yw85mvm1oFsGhaYDc")
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?
If it's not the code, does anyone know what might be causing this?

thanks :)

***EDIT***

as requested here is the `Event` class

```
class Event{
let id: String
var title: String?
var date: String?
var month: String?
var year: String?
var start: String?
var end: String?
var creator: String?
var notes: String? = nil
var count: String = "0"
var invitees:[String] = []
var location: String? = nil
var canInvite: Bool = false
var isPrivate: Bool = false//false = visible, true = "busy"
var isUserInvited: Bool = false
var isAllDay: Bool = true

init(){
    id = "0"
}

init(_ id: String, title: String, date: String, month: String, year: String, start: String, end: String, count: String = "0", creator: String, privacy: String, allDay: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.date = date
    self.start = start
    self.end = end
    self.creator = creator
    
    self.month = month
    self.year = year
    
    self.count = count
   //MARK: Re-implement these functions 
   // setPrivacy(Int(privacy)!)
   // setAllDay(Int(allDay)!)
    
   // isInvitee()
    
}

public func toArray() -> Dictionary<String,Any>{
    var ev = Dictionary<String,Any>()
    ev["title"] = title
    ev["day"] = date
    ev["month"] = month
    ev["year"] = year
    ev["start"] = start
    ev["end"] = end
    ev["creator"] = creator
    ev["notes"] = notes
    ev["count"] = count
    //ev["invitees"]
    ev["isPrivate"] = isPrivate
    ev["isAllDay"] = isAllDay
    return ev
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to write an array `.addDocument(data: event.toArray()` to Firestore or something else?

Comment: Yeh, `event.toArray()` returns an array that looks like `[String:Any]`

Comment: It’s only ever Boolean, strings and integers that are in the array

Comment: Can you include the Event model in the question. It's probably unrelated to the issue but would be good for completeness.

Comment: @Jay I have added the event class to the end of the question

Comment: Your `toArray` returns a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: omg please tell me I haven't wasted 2 days trying to make this work because it's a dictionary -_- I'm building my app to test a simple `["title":"helloWorld"]` array.... if it works I might throw my Mac at something haha

Comment: now, interestingly, nothing changed on the app's console, but I got a write request when I ran the app (on the Firestore console), and it was allowed through... but now I seem to have broken Firestore, when trying to load it up in the console I get "Error loading documents" where the documents should be... I'll keep you informed on the outcome as I've passed this on to google support... your Dictionary vs Array suggestion looks promising though so thanks @Jay

Comment: You didn't break Firestore. Firebase broke Firestore. They rolled out a change which broke the console for some yesterday and are rolling it back. Rest assured, not your doing. It has been corrected today.

Comment: i know it's not related to your original question, but there's no need to use the toArray() method to serialize your struct into data for firestore. You can just make your struct adopt the Codable protocol. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-yQeAf3bLE

Comment: Yeh, I discovered this back in june

Comment: Made things so much simpler 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question essentially works but is mis-labeled creating confusion. Here's a re-do of the Event class that can return either an array or a dictionary.

```
struct Event {
    let title: String!
    let date: String!
     let month: String!

    func toArray() -> [String: String] {
        let array = [
            "title": title,
            "date": date,
            "month": month,
        ]

        return array as! [String : String]
    }

    func toDict() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
        var ev = Dictionary<String, Any>()
        ev["title"] = self.title
        ev["data"] = self.date
        ev["month"] = self.month

        return ev
    }
}
```

then populate an Event object

```
let event = Event(title: "Test", date: "1", month: "4")
```

and then store it in Firebase as an array

```
ref = db.collection("Events").addDocument(data: event.toArray())
```

then as a dict

```
ref = db.collection("Events").addDocument(data: event.toDict())
```

then in firebase, check the results - you'll see they produce an identical result

What's in the array is a series of key: value pairs and what's in the dictionary is well, a dictionary containing a series of key: value pairs.